# Docker Containers return with incorrect environment variable

Tags: java, docker, rpc, thrift, jib

for a course in my Bachelor's degree, I need to set up RPC communication between 1 master/controller and 3 workers using thrift. The issue I have right now is that while the environment variables are correctly set for the worker containers, when the master sends the ping request, it throws an exception stating the correctly set environment variable is null.
The container images are built using Jib.

EDIT/RESOLVED: I found the answer - In both the pom file of the master and worker, I declared the image name as master-image. It is a simple copy-paste error. Now it works! Thank you so much :)

stack-trace: //I don´t understand why the worker-port is printed as null in the master container.

```
master    | PORT: null
master    | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Cannot parse null string
master    |     at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
master    |     at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
master    |     at org.example.worker.Worker.start(Worker.java:137)
master    |     at org.example.worker.Main.main(Main.java:10)
database  | Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)" because "inputLine" is null
database  |     at org.example.database.DatabaseServer$EchoClientHandler.run(DatabaseServer.java:57)
master exited with code 1
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  master:
    image: master-image:latest
    container_name: master
    build:
      context: ./VS_Project/Master
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - worker_1
      - worker_2
      - worker_3

  worker_1:
    image: worker-image:latest
    container_name: worker_1
    build:
      context: ./VS_Project/Worker
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8081:8080'
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      - PORT=8081

  worker_2:
    image: worker-image:latest
    container_name: worker_2
    build:
      context: ./VS_Project/Worker
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8082:8080'
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      - PORT=8082

  worker_3:
    image: worker-image:latest
    container_name: worker_3
    build:
      context: ./VS_Project/Worker
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8083:8080'
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      - PORT=8083
```

master-code:

```
public void start() {
    //RPC connection to worker

    for(Map.Entry<Integer, String>  worker : workers.entrySet()) {

        try {
            TTransport transport;

            transport = new TSocket(worker.getValue(), worker.getKey());
            transport.open();

            TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
            Calculator.Client client = new Calculator.Client(protocol);

            System.out.print("Calling remote method...worker port:" + worker.getKey()); //e.g. Port 8081

            client.ping();

            System.out.println("done.");

            transport.close();

        } catch (TException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

worker-code:

```
public void start() {

    assert (System.getenv("PORT") != null);
     System.out.println("PORT: " + System.getenv("PORT")); 
    try {
      serverTransport = new TServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("PORT")));
      server = new TSimpleServer(new TServer.Args(serverTransport).processor(new Calculator.Processor<>(new CalculatorImpl())));
      System.out.print("Starting the server... Port:" + System.getenv("PORT"));
      server.serve();
      System.out.println("done.");
    }
    catch (TTransportException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the master process calling `Worker.start()`; can you find that code?  Probably unrelated to this problem, but why do you disable Docker networking for the master container?

Comment: Where did you set the PORT environment variable on your master container? Did you mean to define a `network_mode` environment variable? That looks like you are trying to configure the service's networking, with a setting you likely don't want.

Comment: @DavidMaze  The master is not calling Worker.start(); They are in seperate containers with seperate main functions. That's what confuses me, how does it call it, if it can´t even access it?

Comment: @BMitch I do not need to set a PORT variable on my master. 8080 is fine for it. That´s also why I don´t understand why it prints the port as null on the master container. The sout is being triggered in the worker, not the master.

Comment: Oh, I found the answer! In both the pom file of the master and worker, I declared the image name as <image>master-image</image>. It is a simple copy-paste error. Now it works! Thank you so much :)